# Normal of a null surface and null junction conditions in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, boundary-conditions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am trying to use the null junction formalism in general relativity (as explained in eg http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.43.3763&rep=rep1&type=pdf, "Junctions and thin shells in general relativity using computer algebra: II. The null formalism", by Musgrave and Lake). The problem is when I evaluate the surface stress energy tensor, it seems to depend on the normalization of the normal $n$ of the null surface (see equation (5) in the reference).

So this I do not understand. Is there some more condition one has to impose on a normal vector for a null surface? I thought it should only satisfy $n\cdot e_i=0$ where $e_i$ is a tangent vector on the shell, and $n\cdot n=0$, but this does not determine the overall normalization of $n$ (as opposed to for a time like surface). However, this overall normalization affects my final stress energy tensor $S^{\mu\nu}$ of the matter shell when I evaluate the junction conditions, which does not make sense. Why is this?

Comment: Isn't that addressed in section "2.3. A comment on the stress energy of null shells"?